# Defining commutations rules over arbitrary matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, physics, algebraic-manipulation

I'm working with spin connections with Dirac gamma matrix commutator (I know, mathematica has specific ways to work with it), and I need to define the following rules;

$[\gamma_{0},\gamma_{i}]= 2 \gamma_{0}\gamma_{i} \\$, $[\gamma_{i},\gamma_{0}]= 2 \gamma_{i}\gamma_{0} \\$, $[\gamma_{0},\gamma_{0}]= 0$, $\gamma_{0}.\gamma_{i}.\gamma_{0}.\gamma_{i} = 1 $, $\gamma_{0}.\gamma_{i}.\gamma_{i}.\gamma_{0} = -1$, $\gamma_{0}.\gamma_{i}.\gamma_{j}.\gamma_{k} = 0 $

With ($i,j,k = 1,2,3,4$)

An example of my problem: I have the spin connection:

```
Gammamu = FullSimplify[Series[Table[1/4*Sum[omegamuAB[[μ, a1, b]]*gamma[[a1]].gamma[[b]], {a1, 1, 4}, {b, 1, 4}], {μ, 1, 
  4}], {e, 0, 1}]];
```

Where

```
gamma = {Subscript[γ, 0], Subscript[γ, 1],Subscript[γ, 2], Subscript[γ, 3]};
omegamuAB[[i, 0, i]] = -(Derivative[1][a][t]/n[t])
omegamuAB[[i, i, 0]] = (Derivative[1][a][t]/n[t])
```

(for $i=2,3,4$) are the nonvanishing components of spin-connection. Creating some current using Gammamu, I have:

```
cumuAB = FullSimplify[Series[Table[-I*f[crd]*(I/2*Gammamu[[μ]].gamma[[a1]].gamma[[b]]+I/2*gamma[[a1]].gamma[[b]].Gammamu[[μ]])*f[crd], {μ, 1, 4}, {a1, 1, 4}, {b, 1, 4}], {e, 0, 1}]];
```

My componente cumuAB[[2,1,2]] is:

$\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\left(\gamma _1\cdot\gamma _0-\gamma _0\cdot\gamma _1\right) a'(t)}{4 n(t)}\cdot\gamma _0\cdot\gamma _1+\gamma _0\cdot\gamma _1\cdot\frac{\left(\gamma _1\cdot\gamma _0-\gamma _0\cdot\gamma _1\right) a'(t)}{4 n(t)}\right) f(\{t,\text{x1},\text{x2},\text{x3}\})^2$

Now I'm using a non-smart way to solve the gamma matrix algebra :

```
cumuAB[[2, 1, 2]] /.Subscript[γ, 0].Subscript[γ,1].(((-Subscript[γ, 0].Subscript[γ, 1] + Subscript[γ, 1].Subscript[γ, 0]) Derivative[1][a][t])/(4 n[t])) + (((-Subscript[γ, 0].Subscript[γ, 1] +Subscript[γ, 1].Subscript[γ, 0]) Derivative[1][a][t])/(4 n[t])).Subscript[γ, 0].Subscript[γ,1] -> Derivative[1][a][t]/ n[t]
```

$\frac{a'(t) f(\{t,\text{x1},\text{x2},\text{x3}\})^2}{2 n(t)}$

In simple cases, like this above, I see no problem to use consideration with "/.", but in more complex cases, using "/."  is turning my code into a mass, and more, I'm getting strange dot products, like

$0.\gamma_{0}\gamma_{1}-\gamma_{1}\gamma_{0}.0$

How can I define these gamma matrix algebra in a more usefull way ?

Comment: You might need a package called FeynCalc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ, saddly, FeynCalc isn't explicit, just symbolic. =\