# Working with Dirac Gamma Matrices using FeynCalc - A simple problem

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, feyncalc

I need to obtain this using [package FeynCalc](https://feyncalc.github.io/):
$$
\begin{align}
[\gamma_{0},\gamma_{i}]=& 2 \gamma_{0}\gamma_{i}, \\ 
[\gamma_{i},\gamma_{0}]=& 2 \gamma_{i}\gamma_{0} , \\ 
[\gamma_{0},\gamma_{0}]=& 0, \\
\gamma_{0}.\gamma_{i}.\gamma_{0}.\gamma_{i} =& 1 , \\ \gamma_{0}.\gamma_{i}.\gamma_{i}.\gamma_{0} =& -1.
\end{align}$$.

My gamma matrices are:

$\gamma_{0}= \lbrace \lbrace 0, \ \  \mathbb{I}_{2\times 2} \rbrace,\lbrace \mathbb{I}_{2\times 2}, \ \ 0   \rbrace \rbrace $

$\gamma_{i}= \lbrace \lbrace 0, \ \  -\sigma^{i} \rbrace,\lbrace \sigma^{i}, \ \ 0   \rbrace \rbrace $

and

$\sigma_{1}=\lbrace \lbrace 0, \ \  1 \rbrace,\lbrace 1, \ \ 0   \rbrace \rbrace $

$\sigma_{2}=\lbrace \lbrace 0, \ \  -\mathrm i \rbrace,\lbrace \mathrm i, \ \ 0   \rbrace \rbrace $

$\sigma_{3}=\lbrace \lbrace 1, \ \  0 \rbrace,\lbrace 0, \ \ -1   \rbrace \rbrace $

I'm working in D-4 space.

Comment: Please give show us what you have already tried. What is the definition of `[]` brackets and $.$? Commutators and matrix product?

Comment: [,] is my commutator, "." Is just multiplication sign. Sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to verify some identities of Dirac gamma matrices in some certain representations. FeynCalc is not a necessity. Actually your choice of Dirac matrices is just the [Weyl (chiral) representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Weyl_(chiral)_basis):

$$
\gamma^\mu = \left(
\begin{array}{ll}
    0 & \sigma^\mu \\
    \overline{\sigma}^\mu & 0
\end{array}\right),
$$

which specifically are

$$
\begin{align}
    \gamma^0 &= \ \tau_1\otimes\sigma^0, \\
    \gamma^i &= \mathrm i \tau_2\otimes\sigma^i.
\end{align}
$$

So according to the above equations, we can define the Dirac gamma matrices ourselves in the Wolfram language:

```
Clear[γ]
SetAttributes[γ, Listable]
γ[μ_] := If[μ == 0, KroneckerProduct @@ PauliMatrix[{1, μ}], 
                  I KroneckerProduct @@ PauliMatrix[{2, μ}]
           ]
```

Then that codes below return `True` means your first three identities are verified:

```
With[{commutator = #.#2 - #2.# &, γList = γ@Range[0, 3]},
     2 TensorProduct[DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1, -1, -1}], γ[0].γ[0]] + Outer[commutator, γList, γList, 1] == 
     2 Outer[Dot, γList, γList, 1]
    ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

As for the last two, it is easy to see:

```
Table[Dot @@ γ[{0, i, 0, i}], {i, 3}] == -Table[Dot @@ γ[{0, i, i, 0}], {i, 3}] == ConstantArray[IdentityMatrix[4], 3]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

**Bonus**

To verify what speaks of the Clifford algebra, also the defining features of Dirac gamma matrices

$$
\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} = 2\eta^{\mu\nu}I_4,
$$

one can compare the outcomes of the two pieces of codes:

```
With[{anticommutator = #.#2 + #2.# &, γList = γ[Range[0, 3]]},
     Outer[anticommutator, γList, γList, 1] // MatrixForm
    ]

2 DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1, -1, -1}]~TensorProduct~IdentityMatrix[4] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Thank you sou much. What I need is a spin-connection, like I wrote in this topic: [Defining commutations rules over arbitrary matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182822/defining-commutations-rules-over-arbitrary-matrix)

Comment: using DiracSimplify my work is almost done, now I need just impose 

$\gamma_{0}\gamma_{i}\gamma_{0}\gamma_{i}=1$, 
$ \gamma_{0}.\gamma_{i}.\gamma_{i}.\gamma_{0} = -1$, 
$\gamma_{0}\gamma_{i}\gamma_{i}\gamma_{j}=0$

With FeynCalc package, is it possible?